# Redirect One Directory from https to http

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http, mod-rewrite, https

For some reason, I'm seeing one directory's contents showing up on Google with https URLs.  Since this breaks some page elements, I need to check for that particular directory for https requests and redirect to http.  Https is used within several other directories, so I don't want to make a blanket redirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use that in your root `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^particularDirectory/? http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]
```

Or that in your `particularDirectory/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]
```

Comment: That Works! Thanks Croises!  The only modification I had to make was to remove the [L] flag since there are many other rewrites happening...  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

There are many sample script for this. And if you understand rewrite rules it's not that hard. I found this one at ServerFault that should work for you. Don't forget to alter it for you specific directory (if you don't want everything to be rewritten to https).

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```